# limit git bash execution on Windows

Tags: windows, directory, permissions, git-bash

I've had some .... incidents with git bash recently (no loses, had backup copy), and to prevent more times this can happen I want to limit where Git Bash can run.
If I, for example want to operate on, for example "C:\xampp\htdocs\symfonyprojects", I want that Git Bash can only operate there, and not, in "C:\xampp\htdocs", for example, and if I try, it launch an error.
Is that possible?

Comment: Not sure how to implement it or if it is at all adviseable but you could change your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files (or make them if you don't have either) and set it to quit out of the terminal if the directory doesn't match the directory you want it to work in. Sorry I can't be of more help